# Visual Studio cannot find or open PBD file for ig7icd64.dll and igdusc64.dll.

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, visual-c++, dll

```
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Velu\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\OpenGL.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\glew32.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ddraw.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dciman32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dinput8.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\XInput1_4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\hid.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ig7icd64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdusc64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wtsapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'
The thread 0x2bb8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x107c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x11b0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2bb4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\XInput1_4.dll'
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\hid.dll'
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dinput8.dll'
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'
The thread 0x2b94 has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The thread 0x2b4c has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The thread 0x2b84 has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[10908] OpenGL.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

I am trying to use Visual Studio with OpenGL 4.0. I at first had a problem where **all** the dll's wouldn't load but then I found the answer on this site which was enabling Microsoft Symbol Servers. But now Visual Studio complains that it  cannot find or open the PDB file for ig7icd64.dll and igdusc64.dll. I am using Windows 10 with Visual Studio,GLEW,and GLFW. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. The `ig7icd64.dll` and `igdusc64.dll` are Intel drivers and Intel doesn't provide the symbol files (PDB). Only if you roll back to the inbox driver that is part of Windows you get PDBs from Microsoft, but those drivers are old and outdated.

So you have to ignore this message and continue debugging.